# MySQL: Trigger Update with random value from another tables column

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger that updates a column with a random value from another tables column anytime that a value for that row changes.

In the attached image I have two tables, list and users. I would like for users.random to update with a new random value from the list.fruit column anytime first_name or last_name in the users table gets updated / changes.

If sam smith gets changed to andrew smith then I want pear to be updated to another random fruit from the fruits list.

This example has been obfuscated, but should explain what I’m trying to achieve.

[image: tables]

Comment: Show an example. Initial state, final state. And define what is "from **another tables** column".

Comment: Can my question be re-opened now with the edits I’ve made?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a fiddle (or add CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts for both tables at least).

Comment: @Akina, can you elaborate? I’ll Google it but I’ve never heard of a fiddle. What’s the advantage over a trigger, or is the fiddle suggested cause the trigger isn’t possible? Thanks!

Comment: Look the sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6674ba0fc1377328490e896617ab074. Make your fiddle, check carefully, provide the link.

Comment: @Akina Ok, I’ll try creating a fiddle later this morning. I’ll reply back with the link. Thanks.

Comment: @Akina Here is my fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72af478a4118ffbc8597f706d52b8183. I added in one of the triggers I was playing with. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_test
BEFORE UPDATE
ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.random = ( SELECT fruits
                   FROM list
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c2b825177893766c054676f05f8e3ca

Comment: Thanks, that’s perfect! Out of curiosity, instead of a trigger is it possible the same functionality could be applied to a generated column?

Comment: @Kburgen9 No. Generated column cannot use subquery or non-deterministic function.