# MySQL: Conditional Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger that conditionally updates a column with a random value from another tables column.

Previously I received help to create a trigger that updates a column with a random value from another tables column: [MySQL: Trigger Update with random value from another tables column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709787/mysql-trigger-update-with-random-value-from-another-tables-column). I’m trying now to make it conditionally based on another columns value.

If the users.selection column = ‘fruits’ then random select from fruits.
If the users.selection column = ‘animals’ then random from animals.
If neither ‘fruits’ nor ‘animals’ don’t update.

Here is a db-fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bc76ed2c104dad0e27dd35b1da112a7

Major thanks to @Akina for getting me this far! Lots to learn.

Update (May 29th):

I still can’t figure it out. I thought maybe I would need a SELECT with IF statement first to return the selection column value but that didn’t seem to work. Basically I have tried a lot of different combinations using these examples below as templates. None of them seem to bring my closer.

Anyone have any ideas?

Examples:

```
SELECT T1.ID, IFNULL(T1.name, T2.name) AS name
FROM firsttable T1
LEFT JOIN secondtable T2
ON T1.T2_id = T2.id

SET final_price= CASE
   WHEN currency=1 THEN 0.81*final_price
   ELSE final_price
END

SET col = (
SELECT other_col
FROM other_table
WHERE other_table.table_id = table.id
);

SELECT book_name,isbn_no,
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_mast WHERE pub_lang='English')>
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_mast WHERE pub_lang<>'English'),
(CONCAT("Pages: ",no_page)),(CONCAT("Price: ",book_price))) 
AS "Page / Price"
FROM book_mast;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to conditionally define what does what, if selection is fruit, then do something. else if selection is animals, then do another thing.

e.g:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_test
            BEFORE UPDATE
            ON users 
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN  
              IF (NEW.selection = 'fruits') THEN
                SET NEW.random = ( SELECT fruits
                   FROM list
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 );
              ELSEIF (NEW.selection = 'animals') THEN
                SET NEW.random = ( SELECT animals
                   FROM list
                   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 );
            END IF;
            END;
```